# FFMPEG add audio to a video but clip it to the video length

Tags: ffmpeg, video-encoding

I'm trying to create a video from an image sequence and add audio with FFMPEG

The frame sequence is only 25 frames long but the audio is several minutes. I want FFMPEG to clip the audio to the length of the frame sequence.

This is the command I have tried:

```
ffmpeg -i input_images%04d.jpg -pix_fmt yuv420p -vcodec mjpeg -qmin 1 -qmax 1 -r 25 -i audio_file.mp3 -ar 22050 -ab 192k -aframes 25 output.mov
```

This results in a video with the first image sequence but the full length audio. -aframes is ignored. Any ideas?

Comment: sorry but it's not a programming question and better belongs to superuser.com. if you'd like to implement required functionality using `libffmpeg` please change your question accordingly

Comment: Noted. I wasn't aware of superuser.com. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for `-shortest` option:

> -shortest
>   Finish encoding when the shortest input stream ends.